# promise wait to start another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have function which run under promise and I want to start another function promise resolved. But I could not do that. Below is my promise function

```
var promise1
  $(document).ready(function() {
    promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     getData(url).then(function(data) {
       // do something
     })
    })
  })
```

Now on the same page different web part we want another function run but only after finish of above function

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
promise1.then(function(d) {
      var commentURL ="https://xxxx"
      loadComments(commentURL)
    })
})
```

but second function never runs, please help me

Comment: call promise1 in success event of getData

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if you gave us a more complete picture of your overall structure, we could suggest a way of doing what you're doing that would be more appropriate.

But answering your actual question: You'd have to create the promise immediately, rather than in a `ready` callback, but resolve it in the `ready` callback.

**If** you have to wait for `ready` before calling `getData`, then this is one of the rare situations where it makes sense to use `new Promise` even though you already get a promise from `getData` (because of the time delay, you need a promise immediately, but you want to wait to call `getData`):

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
     getData(url).then(resolve).catch(reject);
  });
});
```

**But**, unless you really have to wait for `ready` to call `getData`, don't (it doesn't immediately make sense to wait to get some data until the page's DOM is complete):

```
var promise1 = getData(url);
```

Comment: Well this works. But another function is not executing may be it is my code issue

Comment: @Milind - I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a promise with `new Promise` when you already get a promise from a function call, like is your case with `getData`. Wrapping that in a `new Promise` callback is known as the [Promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/5459839). Try to avoid it.

Do it like this:

```
var promise1;
$(document).ready(function() {
    promise1 = getData(url).then(function(data) {
        // If you want to pass something on to the next `then`, then return it here:
        return someData;
    });
});
```

The other part can stay like you had it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     promise1.then(function(d) {
        var commentURL ="https://xxxx"
        loadComments(commentURL)
    });
});
```

This can only work if `promise1` has been initialised by the first code block. If for some reason the code blocks are executed in reversed order and you cannot change this order, then wrap a resolving promise in the second code block, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     Promise.resolve().then(function () {
         return promise1;
     }).then(function(d) {
         var commentURL ="https://xxxx"
         loadComments(commentURL)
     });
});
```